# How do I filter pandas dataframe based on whether the groups contain a certain column value?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I have the following data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'encounter' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    'project_id' : ['A','A','A','B','C','C'],
    'datetime' : ['2017-01-18','2017-01-18','2017-01-18','2019-01-18','2020-01-18','2020-01-18'],
    'diagnosis' : ['F12','A11','B11', 'C11', 'F12', 'B22']
})
```

Each **encounter** is unique (and has a corresponding unique `project_id` and `datetime`) and denotes a clinician diagnosing a patient with 1 or more diagnoses. I'm trying to find all the groups that contain a particular diagnosis e.g. *F12*.

I don't want to just filter for *F12*; I want to groupby encounter (+/- `project_id` and `datetime`?) and filter for groups containing *F12*, so I can also see what other diagnoses are common with *F12*.

I'm unsure how to go about this - I've tried setting multi-indexes/different groupby approaches etc. but I'm not getting anywhere. For the above data, my desired output would be the same df excluding **Row 3** as below:

| Index | encounter | project_id | datetime | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | 2017-01-18 | F12 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2017-01-18 | A11 |
| 2 | 1 | A | 2017-01-18 | B11 |
| 4 | 3 | C | 2020-01-18 | F12 |
| 5 | 3 | C | 2020-01-18 | B22 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to check if any value is F12 in the group and perform [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['diagnosis'].eq('F12').groupby(df['encounter']).transform('any')]
```

Or, alternatively with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df.groupby('encounter').filter(lambda d: d['diagnosis'].eq('F12').any())
```

output:

```
   encounter project_id    datetime diagnosis
0          1          A  2017-01-18       F12
1          1          A  2017-01-18       A11
2          1          A  2017-01-18       B11
4          3          C  2020-01-18       F12
5          3          C  2020-01-18       B22
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter `diagnosis` for `F12` and get matched `encounter` values and then again filter original column `encounter` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['encounter'].isin(df.loc[df['diagnosis'].eq('F12'), 'encounter'])]
print (df)
   encounter project_id    datetime diagnosis
0          1          A  2017-01-18       F12
1          1          A  2017-01-18       A11
2          1          A  2017-01-18       B11
4          3          C  2020-01-18       F12
5          3          C  2020-01-18       B22
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted as you need all encounters which is associated in any way to diagnosis 'F12' in the problem. See if this works.

```
df[df['project_id'].isin(df.loc[df['diagnosis'].eq('F12'), 'project_id']) | df['datetime'].isin(df.loc[df['diagnosis'].eq('F12'), 'datetime'])]
```